# Show subfolder file

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-filesystem, google-chrome-app

I have a problem with reading files located in folders and subfolders.
example:

- Main Folder
    - File 1
    - File 2
       - Subfolder
       -file 1
       -file 2

I can read all the files. But when in a sub-folder, there is also a folder, I can not. If the structure is:

- Main Folder
    - File 1
    - File 2
     - Subfolder
       -file 1
       -file 2
          - Another subfolder
            - File 1

How is it possible to read all the files contained in the main folder?
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I found the solution. My mistake was from my hook.

Comment: If you found your solution, go ahead and post it and answer your own question. It will help others who may be facing the same problem.

Comment: Here is my solution. Sorry, I had not thought to put it.

var numDirs = 0;
var numFiles = 0;
function loadDirEntry(_chosenEntry) {
    var directoryReader = _chosenEntry.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(readerSuccess, errorHandler);
}
function readerSuccess(entries) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        if (entries[i].isFile === true) {
            numFiles++;
            displayFiles(entries[i]);
        } else if (entries[i].isDirectory === true) {
            numDirs++;
            loadDirEntry(entries[i]);
        }
    }
}